# Python Requests, how to bind to different source ip for each request?

Tags: python, sockets, python-requests, python-sockets

I'm trying to learn some python, and i'm having issues with the logic in what I want to test.
Currently my code is written in a way that binding to source_address doesn't change when the process starts

```
import socket
import requests

real_create_conn = socket.create_connection

def set_src_addr(*args):
    address, timeout = args[0], args[1]
    source_address = ('201.X.X.1', 0)
    return real_create_conn(address, timeout, source_address)

socket.create_connection = set_src_addr

r = requests.get('http://www.mywebpage.com/main')
print r.status_code 
if r.status_code == 404
   print "Webpage Down!"

r = requests.get('http://www.mywebpage.com/blog')
print r.status_code 
if r.status_code == 204
   print "Error occured!"
```

I'm looking to do something like this where

```
import socket
import requests


While 1: 

      #bind to source address 201.X.X.1
      #Send request to main webpage
      #print result
      time.sleep(300) # 5 minutes

      #bind to source address 201.X.X.12
      #Send request to blog webpage
      #print result
      time.sleep(300) # 5 minutes
```

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: how to bind to different source ip for each request?

Answer (score 18):

For *each* request, there is no elegant solution, but you'll need to use a requests Session object and mount a new transport adapter for each request.

You can find example code for the transport adapter in [this issue comment](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2008#issuecomment-40793099), or you can use the adapter included in the `requests-toolbelt` package, like so

```
import requests
from requests_toolbelt.adapters import source

responses = []
s = requests.Session()
for source_ip, url in list_of_sources_and_urls:
    new_source = source.SourceAddressAdapter(source_ip)
    s.mount('http://', new_source)
    s.mount('https://', new_source)
    responses.append(s.get(url))
```

That assumes that `list_of_sources_and_urls` looks like

```
 [('127.0.0.1', 'https://google.com'),
  ('255.255.254.0', 'https://yahoo.com'),
  # ...
  ]
```

Comment: interesting way of doing it, thank you for the solution, but do you think it's also a viable solution to assign source ip + Get request with threading as another solution to this problem ? let's say thread 1 = socket assign source address#1 + r = requests.get#1, thread 2 =  socket assign source address#2 + r = requests.get#2 ?  Thanks