# Python requests ip endpoint

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have a few IP addresses and I need to 'bind' a request to one or another one of them dynamically. I am using python `requests` library to make `http` requests (`GET` or `POST`). Is it possible to `bind` my requests to needed IP?

PS:
I asked because it is possible in .net C# to bind socket to needed output IP (`IPEndPoint`) so I thought it may be possible in python `requests` too.

Comment: Could you provide a minimum working example of what you've got so far and tell us what you've tried to get what you want?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28773033/python-requests-how-to-bind-to-different-source-ip-for-each-request

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is the socket library. Here is an example to get you started.

```
import socket

HOST = ''                 # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 50007              # Arbitrary non-privileged port
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected by', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data: break
    conn.sendall(data)
conn.close()
```

Take a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html, and toward the bottom you will see some examples for how to use the library. Version 3 documentation is here - https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html.